# Referencing AD groups in fields without granting them access in Azure DevOps / TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'd like to list the members of a domain security group as options for an Azure DevOps Server / TFS work item field without granting access to those users.
Example:

```
      <FIELD name="Requestor" refname="MyNamespace.Requestor" type="String" reportable="dimension" syncnamechanges="true">
        <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
          <LISTITEM value="MyDomain\SecurityGroup" />
        </ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
        <HELPTEXT>The person who requested the Project</HELPTEXT>
      </FIELD>
```

It seems that unless the group is granted access by membership in a DevOps group, the following error is produced on work item import:

> TF26171: User/group 'MyDomain\SecurityGroup' is not found.
> TF26204: The account you entered is not recognized. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator to add your account.

This also holds true for the field restriction `<VALIDUSER group="MyDomain\SecurityGroup" />` in place of the LISTITEM approach.

However, I don't want to grant access to that group. Additionally, deny permissions can be problematic due to overlap with valid user groups.

Is there any way to make this group available without granting access? Or a different approach to providing an AD group member list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I found to this scenario was to add an Azure DevOps 'Deny Access' group with a respective AD group as a member & then set Deny permissions to the DevOps group. The DevOps group can then be added to another group or directly to a LISTITEM. The gotcha is that deny permissions take precedence, so care needs to be taken to not include DevOps users in that AD group.

This workaround solves the need to select AD group users but not grant them access to the DevOps app.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make this group available without granting access? Or a different approach to providing an AD group member list?

I am afraid there is no such way to make this group available without granting access.

According to the document [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=azure-devops-2020#require-read-only-and-restrict-values), following rules specify restrictions on specifying or changing the value of a field:

[image]

We could not set rule to grant access to that group.

Besides, just like you test, the group is granted access by membership in a DevOps group, could not granted access by our custom group.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the referenced document section leads to the given conclusion. Can you expound on that connection?
The [Specify a domain qualified account or group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=azure-devops-2020#use-tokens-to-reference-groups) section under Use tokens to reference groups seems to indicate this is possible, and makes no mention of needing to be associated with an Azure Devops group.

Comment: @ChrisHill, I could add the reference groups, but there is no such rule to grant **access** to that group. We could only set the rules listed in above answer.